# RuntimeException in JAX-RS RESTful in NetBeans 12.3

Tags: java, rest, web-services, netbeans, jax-rs

I am trying out the examples in the link on Apache NetBeans 12.3:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqaa/index.html

I have built a helloworld class as required:

```
package diam.gateway.ws.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("helloworld")
public class HelloWorld {
    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of helloWorld.HelloWorld
     *
     * @return an instance of java.lang.String
     */
    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getHtml() {
        return "<html><body><h1>Hello, World!!</body></h1></html>";
    }
}
```

I have also generated a web.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"   
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">  
    <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
        <init-param>  
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>diam.gateway.ws.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

I managed to launch the 'Test RESTful Web Services' feature by right-clicking the web application NetBeans project and managed to launch it.

[image: Launched Test RESTful Console in Web Browser]

It throws an error when pressing the 'Test' button on the webpage.

The NetBeans IDE prints the following exceptions:

```
  The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    at diam.gateway.ws.rest.SystemStatusService.<init>(SystemStatusService.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1356)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:248)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:342)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.RequestContext.findOrCreate(RequestContext.java:59)
..........
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on diam.gateway.ws.rest.HelloWorld
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:369)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.RequestContext.findOrCreate(RequestContext.java:59)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:758)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:721)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:691)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:30)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:105)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:51)
...........
```

I did not import any project dependencies in regards to the JAX-RS and left it to NetBeans to sort out the JAX-RS dependencies internally.

The exception is too long and I will just keep it short.

How do I fix this RuntimeException and what is its cause ?

Comment: use should hit correct url. check your context path 1st?

Comment: [1] Update your question to state the versions of Java and Glassfish/Jersey that you are using. Note that NetBeans 12.3 does not support the use of JDK 16. [2] You are using a tutorial from 2010! Obviously there have been significant changes to NetBeans, Java and Jersey/Glassfish since then, so it's not surprising that you have a problem. [3] Can you use a current tutorial instead, such as ["Getting Started with RESTful Web Services"](https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html)?